Phantom Wallet Fees
I wanted to swap memecoin "Crypto President Trump" to Ethereum on Base Network and it always say that "something went wrong" I assume that it is related to few amount of ETH on my account ? Could someone please explain me how much money do I need to do the swap ? Right now I have about 8 $ on ETH


What you need: You need some ETH to cover the transaction fees (gas fees) on the Base Network.

Current situation: You have $8 worth of ETH.

Possible reasons for error: If gas fees are high, $8 might not be enough.


Steps:

Check gas fees: Use a gas fee tracker to see current rates.
Estimate: If gas fees are, for example, $3 per swap, your $8 should be enough for 2-3 swaps.
Add more ETH: If gas fees are higher than $8, you'll need to buy more ETH.
Try again: Once you have enough ETH, retry the swap.

By checking and making sure you have enough ETH for gas fees, you should be able to complete the swap.

So, I have checked current rates on Etherscan and it says that Swap is like low (44.80 USD) average (44.93 USD) and high (46.15 USD) so it means I have to have the equal level of (lets say) 44.93 USD of ETH to make a swap ?! Or am I looking at the wrong rates ?

Network matters: Confirm you're on the Base Network.
Estimate gas fees: Use your wallet or swap tool to get an accurate fee.
Enough ETH?: $8 in ETH should cover low fees on the Base Network. If fees are higher, you’ll need more ETH.
Double-check you're using the Base Network and verify the actual gas fees for an accurate estimate.

Ohhh. I see now. When I swap on Ethereum Network it only works with USDC and it is swapping in a way that after the swap I will get like 30 USD less than the current value of this memecoin e.g. I have 100 USD worth of memecoin and after swap to USDC it will be 77 USDC. Is it common ?

Yes, it is common to experience significant slippage, price impact, and fees when swapping low liquidity memecoins on the Ethereum network.

Okay, thank you very much now. I gladly appreciate your kind help. I will try to buy more Ethereum on Base Network or on Ethereum Network (does it matter which one?) and then try to make a swap. Once again, Thank you for help and If I have still trouble doing this I will be adding new comments here :D

You're welcome! I'm glad I could help. And you should purchase ETH on Base Network, not on Ethereum Network.

Okay, I will do that. Much appreciate once again.
